# Error placement with selectpicker & jQuery Validation plugins

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, select, jquery-validate, errorplacement

I'm working with Bootstrap, selectpicker, and jQuery Validation plugins.

The Select List:

```
<div class="form-group" id="content">
<select id="country" name="country" required>
<option value=''>Select</option>
<option value='1'>USA</option>
</select>
</div>
```

The Selectpicker:

```
$('select').selectpicker();
```

To jQuery Validation need this to can see the Select List:

```
$('#frm-name').validate().settings.ignore = ':not(select:hidden, input:visible, textarea:visible)';
```

And then Validation:

```
$("#frm-name").validate({
        rules: {
            "country": {
                  required: true
            }

        },
        errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
            error.insertAfter("#content");
        }
})
```

The error never shows.

What did I miss?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm not sure where you're going wrong with all this because it's working for me.

Some tips:

1)  You don't need to use `.validate().settings.ignore` when you can just use the `ignore` option within your `.validate()` call.

2)  Although no harm is done, your field `name` of `country` does not need to be enclosed in quotes within `.validate()`.

3)  You do not need the `required` attribute inside your `<select>` element when you've already declared the `required` rule within `.validate()`.

4)  When using the `errorPlacement` callback function, take advantage of the `error` and `element` arguments since the same function is used generically for all of your form elements.  By specifying the `id` of a specific element, you'll be forcing all error messages for all input elements into the same exact location.

5)  Since your `select` element is hidden by the `selectpicker` element and the `selectpicker` element comes *after* the hidden `select`, you'll need to adjust your jQuery to find the proper location in the DOM for your error placement.

Since your `selectpicker` is the next element, `element.next().after(error)` will insert the error message *after* the *next* element in the DOM tree.  Use `if ($(element).is('select'))` to test if the input is a `select` element so as not to interfere with the error placement of the other input elements.

```
errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
    if ($(element).is('select')) {
        element.next().after(error); // special placement for select elements
    } else {
        error.insertAfter(element);  // default placement for everything else
    }
}
```

Full code:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $('#country').selectpicker();

    $("#frm-name").validate({
        ignore: ':not(select:hidden, input:visible, textarea:visible)',
        rules: {
            country: {
                required: true
            }
        },
        errorPlacement: function (error, element) {
            if ($(element).is('select')) {
                element.next().after(error); // special placement for select elements
            } else {
                error.insertAfter(element);  // default placement for everything else
            }
        }
    })

});
```

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/Bccq7/**

Comment: I have been looking for something like this for a few hours